# Why doesnt raw_input in python accept more than 9 special characters

Tags: python-2.7

While writing a decode program in python, I have to get some garbled text as input But only the first 9 characters get accepted why? and how to make it accept everything

code is

```
    print ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"
    print ",,To paste data click on the,,,"
    print ",small icon at top left corner,"
    print ",,Click on Edit and then Paste,"
    print ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"
    print " "
    print " "
    b= raw_input("Enter string: ") or ""
    print b
    x=raw_input("press any key to exit....")
```

Also when I input this text I have to press enter twice

Download the file and then copy paste the input
[link to garbled input](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3w07oe8NRRuUzllY1kyZ25ZRk0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Problem seems to be with the input text, for example if I leave the first 9 characters and copy paste the others they seem to be accepted without a problem

Comment: This works fine on Python 3 by default. Maybe it's a good hint that you should be upgrading by now? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine on my Python 3 (with IDLE). I'm pretty sure the issue is not because Python doesn't accept "more than 9 characters", but because it doesn't accept your 10th character. Try replacing it with something else, and if that works, you should try to figure out how to use all characters within your program.

Also, try adding this on top of your file, it might fix the problem with Python 2:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

If that doesn't work, you should try decoding the string to `utf-8`:

```
b = raw_input('Enter string: ')  # You don't need the `or ""`
b = b.decode('utf-8')
```

Or optionally to your system's default decoding:

```
import sys
b = raw_input('Enter string: ')
b = b.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
```

If none of this works, the problem might be with your environment. Try executing the code in a Power Shell or similar. It might be that Windows's awful command prompt doesn't support all characters.

Comment: Adding # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- doesnt work. and Yes you are right it doesnt accept the 10th character

Comment: still doesnt work. The or part was supposed to have the input text so that I can simply press enter and move forward but if I add that the program simply exits

Comment: Noticed something. It does seem to work properly in idle (without any change). But this problem comes only when I run the py file directly

Comment: @PratheeshRussell Were you using it in Windows's command prompt earlier? Might be that the prompt simply doesn't support all of the characters.

Comment: Yes. that must be the problem. Thank you

Comment: @PratheeshRussell Glad to help. Make sure to accept my question if it worked, I also added the environment change to the end.